# Копирование папок в php

Tags: php

Добрый день. Интересует нет ли готового класса на php который позволяет копировать каталоги с новым именем..
Ранее у меня была подобная библиотека, но сейчас не могу её найти ;(

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё воспользоваться системными функциями копирования используя exec,
ещё полно примеров на http://php.net/manual/ru/function.copy.php